# rewrite php array based on condition

Tags: php, arrays, url-rewriting, conditional-statements

I have one array and i want change the vehicle price based on number of days here is my array want to rewrite the array,i get number of days i get $rental_days and based on that total price is multiplied,now i want to change it such that if days are 1,2,3,4 than charge will be applied if 5,6,7 than the last price will be applicable then how should i rewrite an array based on this condition (total_price)?

```
        $vehicles[$result['vehicle_id']] = array(
            'vehicle_id'    => $result['vehicle_id'],
            'title'         => $result['manufacturer']." ".$result['series'],
            'manufacturer'  => $result['manufacturer'],
            'series'        => $result['series'],
            'year'          => $result['year'],
            'class'         => $result['class'],
            'image'         => $image,
            'image_thumb'   => $image_thumb,
            'description'   => $description,
            'seats'         => $vehicle_meta['seats'],
            'doors'         => $vehicle_meta['doors'],
            'conditioning'  => $vehicle_meta['conditioning'],
            'transmission'  => $vehicle_meta['transmission'],
            'total_price'     => $rc_currency->format($rental_days*$result['rent']),
            'daily_price'     => $rc_currency->format($result['rent'])
        );
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'rewrite an array', u wanna just update the current array? update the current database result?  Just rewrite a new array?? what?

Comment: i get result in array  'total_price' based on number of days but i want to change this value based on number of days.for eg.for no days are greater than 4 then we would charge same for day 5,6,7 than for 8 days new charge will be applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly....

Do your if statement to check for days, then apply the charge to the total at the bottom

Not sure if you want to apply the charge once, or times it by the amount of days as well...I'll leave that to you to figure out

```
      if(($rental_days>0)&&($rental_days<=4)){
       $charge = 12.00; //whatever you charge for 4 days
       } elseif(($rental_days>4)&&($rental_days<=7)){
       $charge = 25.00; //whatever you charge for 567 days
      } elseif($rental_days>7){
       $charge = 40.00; //whatever you charge for 8 days
      } else {$charge = 0;}

      $vehicles[$result['vehicle_id']] = array(
        'vehicle_id'    => $result['vehicle_id'],
        'title'         => $result['manufacturer']." ".$result['series'],
        'manufacturer'  => $result['manufacturer'],
        'series'        => $result['series'],
        'year'          => $result['year'],
        'class'         => $result['class'],
        'image'         => $image,
        'image_thumb'   => $image_thumb,
        'description'   => $description,
        'seats'         => $vehicle_meta['seats'],
        'doors'         => $vehicle_meta['doors'],
        'conditioning'  => $vehicle_meta['conditioning'],
        'transmission'  => $vehicle_meta['transmission'],
        'total_price'     => $rc_currency->format(($rental_days*$result['rent'])+$charge),
        'daily_price'     => $rc_currency->format($result['rent'])
    );
```

Comment: This is better way to rather than write or put any conditional statement inside array